# gridstack.js `'defaults' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridstack

Im trying to follow the tutorial of gridstack.js ([here](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js#basic-usage))

im literally copy and pasting the example to my code. but I get this Error

[image]

and this is the list of library I load from cdnjs

[image]

and this is my code :

```html
<div class="grid-stack">
    <div class="grid-stack-item"
        data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0"
        data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
            <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-stack-item"
        data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="0"
        data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4">
            <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.grid-stack').gridstack();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please write the full page code.

Comment: its might be too long to post the full page code.
but here  https://pastebin.com/3gtSw3AD

Answer (score 0):

Please change jQuery version to be 1.11.1 it seems the 3.3.1 not compatible with grid stack please check this demo https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/blob/develop/demo/rtl.html

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Ive changed the version to 1.11.1 but the same error still appear.

Comment: I'm wondering, it works with me, please double check that you have changed jQuery version and clear browser cache.